How to prevent serialization by Postman's Runner?
I want to loop over a JSON array of objects and use each object directly as body, and send it as it is.
I upload my JSON fil to the runner and add the request to execute. The runner identifies the number of iterateion correctly. I set my request's body to raw and JSON and clear it. Then a add this pre-script:
let currentData = pm.iterationData.toJSON();
console.log("Sending request body:", JSON.stringify(currentData));
pm.request.body.raw = JSON.stringify(currentData);

But when I start a run, instead of sending my data, Postman send its serialized version.
How to prevent this behaviour and send just the data from the JSON file?
My data:
[
    {
        "title": "Project A Title",
        "role": "Project A Role",
        "from": "1970-01",
        "to": "1970-12"
    },
    {
        "title": "Project B Title",
        "role": "Project B Role",
        "from": "1971-01",
        "to": "1971-12"
    }
]

What Postman sends:
Iteration 1:
{
    "id": "e32d5e83-bd44-4782-9b59-0f8de6bb7f0d",
    "values": [
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "Project A Title",
            "key": "title"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "Project A Role",
            "key": "role"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "1970-01",
            "key": "from"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "1970-12",
            "key": "to"
        }
    ]
}

Iteration 2:
{
    "id": "6309e0a7-53e9-4286-a5fd-9da50dc866c1",
    "values": [
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "Project B Title",
            "key": "title"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "Project B Role",
            "key": "role"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "1971-01",
            "key": "from"
        },
        {
            "type": "any",
            "value": "1971-12",
            "key": "to"
        }
    ]
}


You just need to change toJSON() to toObject().
let currentData = pm.iterationData.toObject();
console.log("Sending request body:", JSON.stringify(currentData));
pm.request.body.raw = JSON.stringify(currentData);


